# Nemenyi Test Python

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, python

Lets say we have a 2D matrix defined as follows

```py
test_matrix = np.array  
     ([[0.60785324, 0.61440499, 0.58259179, 0.62093956, 0.60601833,
        0.62020864, 0.63394675, 0.62714066, 0.61424252, 0.63700369],
       [0.60633548, 0.60122064, 0.5699726 , 0.60301325, 0.59595725,
        0.59791083, 0.61473163, 0.60286638, 0.60811504, 0.63009068],
       [0.61641485, 0.62513144, 0.58934988, 0.61052178, 0.61656882,
        0.62829806, 0.64243387, 0.6219826 , 0.62502894, 0.64509667],
       [0.48035034, 0.50608212, 0.48603005, 0.48932625, 0.46643116,
        0.49742805, 0.49639745, 0.49457921, 0.49865094, 0.51385576]])
```

representing 4 groups with 10 measurements each.

The means are

```py
array([0.61643502, 0.60302138, 0.62208269, 0.49291313])
```

I want to perform the Nemenyi post hoc test to test significance between groups.

When using the scikit_posthocs library as follows:

```py
nemenyi = scikit_posthocs.posthoc_nemenyi(test_matrix)
```

I get the following output:

```py
       1           2            3          4
1   -1.000000   0.571698    0.945431    0.000794
2   0.571698    -1.000000   0.249753    0.066651
3   0.945431    0.249753    -1.000000   0.000061
4   0.000794    0.066651    0.000061    -1.000000
```

The test seems to reject the null hypothesis when testing groups 1 and 3 with group 4 (as it should). My question is why does the test fail to reject the null when comparing groups 2 and 4?

Comment: reorder the means as 0.49291313, 0.60302138, 0.61643502, 0.62208269, then you should know why not rejecting the null when comparing groups 2 and 4.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Maybe I'm missing something in the way the test is performed? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: 0.60 - 0.49 = 0.11, 0.62 - 0.49 = 0.13.  So when the difference is as small as 0.11 it is not significant. When the difference is as large as 0.13, it is significant. it is very normal. Just like basketball game, team A vs team B with score 80:80, no one win., but for 81:80, team A win, although just 1 point difference.

Comment: Oh I see now! Thank you!